# How to solve undefined reference

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

when I was compiling a C program by GCC compiler, a problems occured as follows:

AppData\Local\Temp\ccGGIeQR.o:bst.c:(.text+0x81): undefined reference to `BiTree_NextOrder'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Link the code with the object file that defines the undefined reference.

Answer (score 3):

The error means that your file `ccGGIeQR.o:bst.c` uses `BiTree_NextOrder` (probably a function), but the implementation of `BiTree_NextOrder` was not found when you tried to link your program.  You have to locate `BiTree_NextOrder` and either link in the corresponding object file or library:

```
gcc ccGGIeQR.o:bst.o BiTree_NextOrder.o -o your_program
gcc ccGGIeQR.o:bst.o -o your_program -lBiTree # perhaps?
```